# Cordova FileTransfer Download - always returns error 3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I've ran into some problems while using cordova plugin File Transfer. Thats my code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
            "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false},
            function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html", "");
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                fileEntry.remove();

                fileTransfer.download( 'http://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_bot.png', sPath + photo.original_name,
                    function (theFile) {
                        alert('success: ' + JSON.stringify(theFile));
                        console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                        // showLink(theFile.toURI());
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                        console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                    },
                    true
                );
            })
    },
    function (error) {
        alert('error request: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
);
```

The fileTransfer.download's error callback is being returned with error code 3, http 401.
I already updated the File and FileTransfer plugins, my cordova version is 4.3.0.
Also checked my config.xml for

```
<access origin="*" />
```

but it's there. 
I tried adding the header Connection: close, but no result.
Tried setting the download's 4th param to its default (false) too - no luck.

Testing on Android tablet.

Anyone anything? Thanks!

Comment: does the tablet have internet connection? error 3 y a connection problem

Comment: Yeah, it does. The app returns an error with code 3 and http_status 401, body: null, exception: null

Comment: the url is the one on your example?

Comment: Yes, the same (http://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_bot.png) is in my code right now - I put that one because I think this should work. But unfortunately it doesnt.

Comment: Which version of Cordova-android? Obtained by running `cordova platform ls`.

Comment: It says: android 3.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found a "solution" to my problem.
What I did was to downgrade the file-transfer plugin version from 0.5.0 to 0.4.8.

If someone ever face similar problem, do as below:

1. Delete the existing file-transfer plugin by running 'cordova plugins list' and then 'cordova plugin remove *name_from_list*'
2. Go to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/releases and download the zip file of 0.4.8 release.
3. Unzip the file in root of your cordova application
4. Run 'cordova plugin add *path_to_unzipped_folder*'

That's it. Seems to be working well, at least the success callback is returned, didn't really test more of it.

Comment: You can also add the specified version using cordova :) just run `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer@0.4.8` to add the specified version.

Comment: I had a similar issue installing cordova-plugin-whitelist and configuring it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That also has helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't create a file then remove it just to get a directory URL. You should be able to obtain just that by doing `fileSystem.root.toURL()` - fileSystem.root is a DirectoryEntry and so contains methods you'd expect to see on a DirectoryEntry.

Just a bit quicker.

**Update**

If you feel inclined to use the file delete method, you should be using toURL() on the FileEntry, not fullPath. I think toURL() returns a URL that can be used throughout HTML app.

But as I say, fileSystem.root.toURL() is preferable. Example code as follows:

Thus, your code becomes:

```
window.requestFileSystem(
    LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
    0,
    function (fileSystem) {
        var url = 'http://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_bot.png',
            dir = fileSystem.root.toURL() + photo.original_name,
            ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.download(url, dir,
            function (fileEntry) {
                alert('Downloaded!');
            },
            function (error) {
                alert('Download error');
                console.log(dir);
            }
        );
    },
    function (error) {
        alert('Error getting file system');
    }
);
```

Try that and see what happens. Might sound stupid, but I presume `photo.original_name` is defined? And there's a '/' between the directory and the filename?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately your solution doesnt work for me, it's the same as it was. I also tried to check the photo.original_name to string, no result. I'm testing on Prestigio tablet, but I just had a chance to run it on SGS4 and the result is the same. error code 3, http_status 401

Comment: And the exact url is file:///storage/emulated/0/cordova_bot.png. And its probably not my connection, I switched the wifi to 4g, still the same - 401

Comment: Which version of Cordova-android are you using? If you run `cordova platform ls` in your project directory it should say there.

Answer (score 0):

If your remote file needs VPN to access, make sure your device is connected to VPN.

In my case I was not connected to VPN on device.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the download url to 
 http://www.{{Domain name}}/abc.pdf

use full url with www

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
let pathToDownload = `${cordova.file.externalDataDirectory}`;
let fileTransfer   = new FileTransfer();    
let url            = encodeURI(`https://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_bot.png`);

fileTransfer.download(url, pathToDownload + "image.png",
    (fileEntry) => {
        console.log('Downloaded!');
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log('Download error');           
    },                      
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was related to ad **http** (*not https*) remote file url.

I solved with this steps:

1. Opening my Project target's **info.plist** file
2. Adding a Key called **NSAppTransportSecurity** as a **Dictionary**.
3. Added a Subkey called **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** as **Boolean** and set its
   value to **YES**.

RefLink: [The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi)