# The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, ios9, xcode7

I am facing the Problem when I have updated my Xcode to 7.0 or iOS 9.0.
Somehow it started giving me the Titled error

> "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security
> policy requires the use of a secure connection"

Webservice Method:

```objectivec
- (void)ServiceCall:(NSString*)ServiceName :(NSString *)DataString
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    [sessionConfiguration setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];
    [sessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{ @"Accept" : @"application/json" }];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ServiceURL]];
    NSLog(@"URl %@%@",url,DataString);
    // Configure the Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", strSessName, strSessVal] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
    request.HTTPBody = [DataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"Post";

    // post the request and handle response
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
        // Handle the Response
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);

            // Update the View
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                // Hide the Loader
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window animated:YES];


            });
            return;
        }
        NSArray * cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL:request.URL];
        for (NSHTTPCookie * cookie in cookies)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@=%@", cookie.name, cookie.value);
            strSessName=cookie.name;
            strSessVal=cookie.value;

        }

        NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
}
```

The service is Running fine for Xcode earlier versions and iOS previous versions But when I have updated to Xcode 7.0 that is on iOS 9.0, it started to give me the Problem like following when I am calling the above web service method. The Logged Error which I am getting is:

> Connection failed: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The
> resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy
> requires the use of a secure connection."
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fada0f31880 {Error
> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"},
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=**MyServiceURL**,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=**MyServiceURL**,
> NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
> App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
> connection.}

I have tried Following Questions and answers but did not get any result there, is there any advance idea how I can remove that service call error?

1. [The resource could not be loaded is ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069393/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-is-ios9)
2. [App Transport Security Xcode 7 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32427300)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609970

Comment: possible duplicate of [App Transport Security Xcode 7 beta 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427300/app-transport-security-xcode-7-beta-6)

Answer (score 1106, accepted):

I have solved it with adding some key in info.plist.
The steps I followed are:

1. Opened my Project target's `info.plist` file
2. Added a Key called `NSAppTransportSecurity` as a `Dictionary`.
3. Added a Subkey called `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as `Boolean` and set its value to `YES` as like following image.

[image]

Clean the Project and Now Everything is Running fine as like before.

Ref Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609970

**EDIT:**
OR In source code of `info.plist` file we can add that:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
       </dict>
  </dict>
```

Comment: I cannot send use mail after i added this. it gives me an error - MailCompositionService quit unexpectedly.

Comment: It's not work at first. You need to add the keys inside Project > Target too

Comment: Here's some helpful Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. Is this error come because of IOS 9??

Comment: @MihirOza: Yep, transport security is a new feature of iOS 9.

Comment: Works like charm. It is not an error, it is just extra security in iOS.

Comment: If I get this error in a different target i. e. a share extension target. Do i add it to that target's `info.plist` or the entire projects?

Comment: If you have no exception domains, just remove any key under `NSExceptionDomains`. Or else it will be an exception to `NSAllowArbitraryLoads`, then you must use https to visit this `exception`

Comment: For Xcode 8.3 / Swift 3 it is `App Transport Security Settings` and `Allow Arbitrary Loads` respectively

Comment: Just adding my 2 cents. If you tried it and it doesn't work. *Make sure you do it on the right info.plist* you can have more than 1 of these files.

Comment: One old project had "ProjectName-Info.plist" file instead of "Info.plist", noticed only after while trying to create new info.plist file. Added to this file and worked great.

Comment: You should NOT disable it! It's unsafe. Check https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

Comment: I have tried above solution, http based apis are being called but I can not stream video. any idea how we can stream video that is http based?

Answer (score 334):

Be aware, using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true` in the project's `info.plist` allows all connection to any server to be insecure. If you want to make sure only a **specific domain** is accessible through an insecure connection, try this:

[image]

Or, as source code:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Clean & Build project after editing.

Comment: thanks for your answer just NSAllowArbitaryLoads didn't work for me adding NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads did the trick

Comment: I also added these two keys: <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>

It made it load a LOT quicker too.

Comment: Note: I'm using XCode 8 now: If you're doing this manually, make sure to right click on the domain > Value Type > Dictionary to add "..AllowsInsecure..." and "...IncludesSubdomains"

Comment: Not working if I specify port number after domain.com. (domain.com:3001 for example)

Answer (score 59):

**Transport security** is provided in iOS 9.0 or later, and in OS X v10.11 and later.

So by default only **https** calls only allowed in apps. To turn off App Transport Security add following lines in **info.plist** file...

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

For more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: But, this is still not allowing me to make HTTP call to any domain. Is there any clue why is it happening?

Comment: Even its a HTTP URL, the URL shoulb be bverified or should have a vlid SSL certificate.

Answer (score 39):

For iOS 10.x and Swift 3.x [below versions are also supported] just add the following lines in 'info.plist'

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: For 10.x and Swift 3.x, I had seen elsewhere that the keys were actually AppTransportSecurity and AllowsArbitraryLoads but those were wrong. the NS prefix is still needed for these keys, even for Swift 3.x. The error went away when I relied on the NS prefix for these keys.

Answer (score 36):

In Swift 4   You can use

->Go Info.plist

-> Click plus of Information properties list

->Add **App Transport Security Settings** as dictionary

-> Click Plus icon **App Transport Security Settings**

-> Add **Allow Arbitrary Loads** set **YES**

Bellow image look like

[image]

Answer (score 25):

I have solved as plist file.

Add a NSAppTransportSecurity : Dictionary.

Add Subkey named " NSAllowsArbitraryLoads " as Boolean : YES

[image]

Answer (score 22):

This  is Apple's way of forcing tighter security on your apis(forced to use https over http). I'll explain how to remove this security setting.

---

Most answers on here point out adding this key to your info.plist
[image]

This alone did not solve this problem for me.
I had to add the same key to inside

`Project -> Targets -> Info -> Custom iOS Target Properties`
[image]

---

This will allow insecure connections to happen from anyone however. If you want to allow only a specific domain to use make insecure connections, you can add the following to your info.plist.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! I only edited the plist file before which didnt work. Im surprised how other people got it working that way

Answer (score 19):

The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection working in Swift 4.03.

Open your pList.info as source code and paste:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 13):

**From Apple documentation**

*If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively. If you have an existing app, you should use HTTPS as much as you can right now, and create a plan for migrating the rest of your app as soon as possible. In addition, your communication through higher-level APIs needs to be encrypted using TLS version 1.2 with forward secrecy. If you try to make a connection that doesn't follow this requirement, an error is thrown. If your app needs to make a request to an insecure domain, you have to specify this domain in your app's Info.plist file.*

To Bypass App Transport Security:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

To allow all insecure domains

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Read More: [Configuring App Transport Security Exceptions in iOS 9 and OSX 10.11](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Xcode 8.0 and swift 3.0 or 2.2

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In Xcode 7.1 onwards(swift 2.0)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In XCode 12.5. IOS 14. I made following entries

[image]

This is how info.plist source code looks like

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Working for me.....

Answer (score 7):

If you are not a big fan of XML, then just add below tag in your plist file.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

iOS 9 (may) force developers to use **App Transport Security** exclusively. I overheard this somewhere randomly so I don't know whether this is true myself. But I suspect it and have come to this conclusion:

**The app running on iOS 9 will (maybe) no longer connect to a Meteor server without SSL.**

This means running meteor run ios or meteor run ios-device will (probably?) no longer work.

In the app's info.plist, `NSAppTransportSecurity [Dictionary]` needs to have a key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads [Boolean]` to be set to `YES` or Meteor needs to use `https` for its `localhost server` soon.

Answer (score 5):

**If you are using Xcode 8.0 to 8.3.3 and swift 2.2 to 3.0**

> In my case need to change in URL **http://** to **https://**  (if not working then try)

```
Add an App Transport Security Setting: Dictionary.
Add a NSAppTransportSecurity: Dictionary.
Add a NSExceptionDomains: Dictionary.
Add a yourdomain.com: Dictionary.  (Ex: stackoverflow.com)

Add Subkey named " NSIncludesSubdomains" as Boolean: YES
Add Subkey named " NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads" as Boolean: YES
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For those of you developing on localhost follow these steps:

1. Tap the "+" button next to `Information Property List` and add `App Transport Security Settings` and assign it a `Dictionary` Type
2. Tap the "+" button next to the newly created `App Transport Security Settings` entry and add `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` of type `Boolean` and set its value to `YES`.
3. Right click on `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` entry and click the "Shift Row Right" option to make it a child of the above entry.
4. Tap the "+" button next to the `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` entry and add `Allow Arbitrary Loads` of type `Boolean` and set its value to `YES`

Note: It should in the end look something like presented in the following picture

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use HTTPS and not HTTP in your URL and it will work

Comment: Unless, of course, you cannot use HTTPS because Apple does not like self-signed certifcates.  Do you not have that problem?

Comment: In my case, it works perfectly since I changed to HTTPS

Comment: but do you use a self-signed or CA signed certificate?  Just curious.  Sort of a separate issue, of course, but figured I would ask.

Comment: I didn't work on the server side, I don't know to be honest :(

Comment: Setting up HTTPS connection on some server environments (shared hosting) might be difficult.

Comment: Don't tell or force people to use HTTPS, they might have some other requirements. That is not an answer at all.

Comment: Not if you are required to use HTTP

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you change the right info.plist file**.

This is the ***second time*** I waste time on this issue, because I didn't notice that I'm changing info.plist under MyProjectNameUITests.

Answer (score 3):

Open your **pList.info** as **Source Code** and at bottom just before `</dict>` add following code,

```
 <!--By Passing-->
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>your.domain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <!--End Passing-->
```

And finally change `your.domain.com` with your base Url. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use firebase, it will add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent = true` in the `NSAppTransportSecurity` section, and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true` will not work

Comment: Thanks for this information. You saved me hours of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this with a combination of many of the mentioned options. I’ll include a checklist of all of the things I had to do to get this to work.

In short:

1. Set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true for my watch extension (not my watch app).
2. Ensure I was using `https` and not `http`.

---

**Step one:**

Firstly and most obviously I had to add an `NSAppTransportSecurity` key as a dictionary in my watch extension’s `info.plist` with a subkey called `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as a boolean set to true. *Only* set this in the watch extension and not the watch app’s plist. Although take note that this allows all connections and could be insecure.

[image]

or

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

---

**Step two:**

Then I had to make sure that the url I was trying to load was `https` and not just `http`. For any urls that were still http I used:

**Swift**:

`let newURLString = oldURLString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("http", withString: "https")`

**Obj-C:**

`NSString *newURLString = [oldURLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@“http” withString:@“https”];`

Answer (score 2):

For XCode 13, adding `Allow Arbitrary Loads` isn't such a trivial job. Because by default there is no key named `App Transport Security Settings`.

You have to discover how to add a new root level key, by pressing any of the plus buttons that you see under Info/Custom iOS Target Properties.

See details in this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400983/1644618

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use `https` calls only in Apps. Transport security was introduced in iOS 9.0, allowing only `https` calls from apps by default.

However, if you still want to allow all non `https` calls -
Add `NSAppTransportSecurity` (Dictionary) in Info.plist and
Add Subkey named `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` with the boolean value YES.
After update, plist should look like

[image]

**STEPS**

- Open Info.plist
- Click **+** under the Information properties list
- Add App Transport Security Settings(`NSAppTransportSecurity`) as a dictionary
- Click **+** under added App Transport Security Settings
- Add Allow Arbitrary Loads(`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`) as boolean and set the value to YES

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in the case of a self hosted parse-server using a one year signed certificate rather than the option "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads"

Parse Server as any node.js server presents a **public https url** that you have to specify. For instance:

parse-server --appId  --masterKey  --publicServerURL https://your.public.url/some_nodejs

Feel free to give a look to my [configuration files](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/64)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open info.plist file
2. Add a Key called `App Transport Security Settings` as a Dictionary.
3. Add a Subkey called `Allow Arbitrary Loads` as Boolean and set its value to YES as in the following image.
4. Finally, clean the Project (with Command+Shift+K) and done.

[image: image of the solution in info.plist]

Or, in code:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>

    // .....

</dict>
```

Comment: This adds nothing that isn't found in several of the existing answers. Also, if you find that you are posting the same answer to more than one question then you should instead flag the question as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
// on the top of last two  (</dict> and </plist>)
```

paste the below snipped code

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Inside `Ios` folder > `Project Name` > `info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>   //Add this line
        <true/>                             //Add this line
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
       </dict>
  </dict>
```

then `cd ios`

finally `pod install`