# iOS 9 Basic HTTP Request

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

I have researched the last few hours and cannot find an example that works in iOS 9 in my Swift application. I simply want to do an HTTP GET request to a url "http://www.example.com". The URL will return XML data that will be parsed but for now I just want to get the HTTP GET command to run.

I am new to Xcode but have some programming background but cannot figure out how to get a URL to do a GET command

I have a button that I have and I want it to run the HTTP GET request when the button is pressed. When looking through the NSURLSession examples online, I cannot find one that won't throw a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated. Below is one I found but its throwing a bunch of errors. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground
func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            callback("”, error.localizedDescription),
        } else {
            var result = NSString(data: data, encoding:
                NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            callback(result, nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: “http://www.google.com")!)

httpGet(request){
    (data, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println(data)
    }
}
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaned-up, Swift 2 rendition of your code sample might look like:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest, callback: (String?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            callback(nil, error)
            return
        }

        callback(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding), nil)
    }
    task.resume()
}

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)

httpGet(request) { string, error in
    guard error == nil && string != nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    print(string!)
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

This fixes the obvious errors in the original code snippet (the occasional use of `“` and `”` instead of `"`; the use of the deprecated `println` rather than `print`; the extraneous `,` after the first `callback` call; add some missing optional unwrapping; etc.).

This also addresses a few other issues, namely,

- Use `String` rather than `NSString`;
- Make `String` parameter of `callback` optional (rather than returning `""` when there was an error);
- I think it's preferable to return the the actual `NSError` object rather than just the localized description (at some point, you might actually care about the `code` or `domain` of the error)
- Use of Swift 2 `guard` statements to guard against any errors that occur.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much! Wow, after 4 hours I finally got it to work! Now off to parsing the return XML into variables. . .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **GET** method I use:

```
func get(url : String, successHandler: (response: String) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        //in case of error
        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        let responseString : String = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        successHandler(response: responseString)
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

Since you're making a plain HTTP request, you need to modify your `Info.plist` file. Add the following key after the last array element if your file was created from the default template (as in a new single view application for example).

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>google.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

A less secure approach that allows for an arbitrary number of domains:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Finally, you can test the above method in the `viewDidLoad()` function along with any callback. I called my callback `updateWebview` but yours can be called anything of course.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = "http://www.google.com"
    get(url, successHandler: {(response) in self.updateWebview(response)});
}

func updateWebview(let html: String) {
    print(html)
}
```

---

An example that uses **POST** with parameters:

```
func post(url : String, params : String, successHandler: (response: String) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    let params = String(params);
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        //in case of error
        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        let responseString : String = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        successHandler(response: responseString)
    }
    task.resume();
}
```

Comment: This could be a problem with the Info.plist. The issue is that the http request could be going to any IP address that I will have the user define depending on their system. How would you add the rule if you didn't know what the domain would be?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi