# Cocoa - What's wrong with WebView and html in El Capitan?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, osx-elcapitan

my app should open a website from my server in web view.
Everything works fine until I tried to use my app with EL Captian.

Here I dumbed the code down:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSString *urlText = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"urlTextField"];
    [[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlText]]];
    return;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


- (IBAction)navigateURL:(id)sender {
    NSString *urlTextField = [self.urlTextField stringValue];
    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlTextField];
    NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[[self webView] mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
}
```

this works fine with sites like Wikipedia or Apple.com, but with El Capitan I have no chance to connect to my site (http://resolvo-app.com).

Thanks for help!

Comment: Its probably AppSecurity issue. only HTTPS sites are allowed by default. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32631185/366346

Comment: There is nothing I could do to make my app running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi)

Comment: @kjg Can you post the errors from console ?

Comment: Thanks so much Eric D. App is working :)