# Why is the image not being added to the array?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to append images retrieved from parse database, but nothing is being added to the UIImage array. How do I append the retrieved images?

```
 var arrayOfFriends: [UIImage] = []

 func getFriendPic(){

    var imagequery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    imagequery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects!{
            let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
            userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if(error == nil){
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    //breakpoint placed on line below, but app crashes with array out of bounds.
                    self.arrayOfFriends.append(image!)
                    print(self.arrayOfFriends)
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger to see what is happening in your code?

Comment: Yes, the array has 0 values

Comment: Yes, but does your `imageQuery` return any objects?  Does the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` return any data?

Comment: This is all I am getting http://puu.sh/kYHud/550773328b.png

Comment: Does the breakpoint in line 50 trigger?  I would suggest your log your error if it isn't nil

Comment: `Array out of bounds` error occurs before reaching the breakpoint

Comment: It would be a good idea to add that information to your question.  What line does that happen on?  It is likely that you have a problem with multi-threading.  Array access isn't thread safe, and you are updating the array from multiple threads as well as reloading the collection view repeatedly

Comment: How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The code was not the problem, it was Xcode, here is the solution to anybody who has the same problem. [The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi)