# does NSURLSession send user-agent automatically

Tags: ios9, watchkit, user-agent, nsurlsession

Does NSURLSession send user-agent automatically when user WatchKit 2.0, iOS 9.0?
Is there a way to verify this within the WatchKit app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, a user agent is automatically provided as part of the default session configuration.

The default `NSURLSession` request header `User-Agent` field includes the Bundle Name (`CFBundleName`) and the Build Number (`CFBundleVersion`) of your watchOS app extension:

```
$(CFBundleName)/$(CFBundleVersion) CFNetwork/808.3 Darwin/16.3.0
```

*Notice that your app's Version Number (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) isn't included. (See [Technical Note TN2420: Version Numbers and Build Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)* for more info.)

For example, for product "Foo" with the Build Number 1, your user agent would be:

```
Foo%20WatchKit%20Extension/1 CFNetwork/808.3 Darwin/16.3.0
```

#### How to Verify?

I don't think there's a way within your app to examine the default user agent field, as it's `nil` (unless you've set it to a custom value).

But, you could use netcat to examine requests sent by the Simulator.

1. Run `nc -l 5678` in Terminal to have netcat listen to requests sent to `localhost` on port `5678`
2. In your app's `Info.plist` file, add the App Transport Security Settings dictionary with the Allow Arbitrary Loads key set to `YES`
3. Add the following code to the start of `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

   ```
   let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:5678/")!
   URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
       let body = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!
       print("body: \(body)")
   }.resume()
   return true
   ```
4. Run your app in the Simulator and see what netcat outputs in Terminal

If your privacy is of no concern, you could use a service like [user-agent.me](http://user-agent.me/) to test on your device.

1. Replace `localhost:5678` above with `user-agent.me`
2. Run your app on your device
3. Examine Xcode's Console output

When you're done verifying, remember to undo all of the changes above.

Comment: Depending on your App Transport Security Settings, you may need to enable arbitrary loads. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32631185/211292

Answer (score 7):

**NSURLSession send User-Agent by default**. 
default User-Agent style like.

```
"User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
```

We can customize the User-Agent.

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "zgpeace User-Agent"]
```

I write a demo for URLSession in the below.

```
     func requestUrlSessionAgent() {
        print("requestUrlSessionAgent")

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        // default User-Agent: "User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
        // custom User-Agent
        config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "zgpeace User-Agent"]
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/anything")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            // ensure there is no error for this HTTP response
            guard error == nil else {
                print ("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            // ensure there is data returned from this HTTP response
            guard let content = data else {
                print("No data")
                return
            }

            // serialise the data / NSData object into Dictionary [String : Any]
            guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
                print("Not containing JSON")
                return
            }

            print("gotten json response dictionary is \n \(json)")
            // update UI using the response here
        }

        // execute the HTTP request
        task.resume()

    }
```

**By the way, the default User-Agent in WKWebView is different, like**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X)
```

You can customize the WKWebView User-Agent

```
webView.customUserAgent = "zgpeace User-Agent"
```

I also write a demo for WKWebView:

```
func requestWebViewAgent() {
        print("requestWebViewAgent")

        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("navigator.userAgent") { (userAgent, error) in
            if let ua = userAgent {
                print("default WebView User-Agent > \(ua)")
            }

            // customize User-Agent
            webView.customUserAgent = "zgpeace User-Agent"
        }
    }
```

**Warning: "User-Agent" is nil from webView, when webView is released. You can set webView object as property to keep the webView.**

**NSURLConnection send User-Agent by default**. 
default User-Agent style like.

```
"User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
```

We can customize the User-Agent.

```
urlRequest.setValue("URLConnection zgpeace User-Agent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
```

I write a demo for URLConnection in the below.

```
func requestUrlConnectionUserAgent() {
    print("requestUrlConnectionUserAgent")

    let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/anything")!
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    // default User-Agent: "User-Agent" = "UserAgentDemo/1 CFNetwork/1121.2.1 Darwin/19.2.0";
    urlRequest.setValue("URLConnection zgpeace User-Agent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (response, data, error) in
        // ensure there is no error for this HTTP response
        guard error == nil else {
            print ("error: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        // ensure there is data returned from this HTTP response
        guard let content = data else {
            print("No data")
            return
        }

        // serialise the data / NSData object into Dictionary [String : Any]
        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("Not containing JSON")
            return
        }

        print("gotten json response dictionary is \n \(json)")
        // update UI using the response here
    }

  }
```

Demo in github: 
https://github.com/zgpeace/UserAgentDemo.git

Answer (score 1):

Related to your question, note that it is possible to manually set the `User-Agent` string for your `NSURLSession` in WatchKit, using a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` object and setting [HTTPAdditionalHeaders.](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionConfiguration/HTTPAdditionalHeaders)

Comment: I know I can add it manually :) I asked if it is added automatically. 10x