# What is the default HTTP user agent string for NSURLConnection and NSURLSession on macOS?

Tags: macos, http, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

[does NSURLSession send user-agent automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36379347/9636) has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380210/9636) that describes the `NSURLSession` default HTTP `User-Agent` string for iOS. I want to know the default format for `macOS` (preferably with supporting documentation), and the default format for `NSURLConnection` as well.

I'm seeing some very old `User-Agent` strings on my site, and I'm trying to verify potential sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows that same code path as the iOS one.

`nsurl/887 CFNetwork/887 Darwin/17.0.0 (x86_64)`

`$(CFBundleName)/$(CFBundleVersion) CFNetwork/$(CFNetworkVersion) Darwin/$(DarwinVersion) ($(Architecture))`

If the program doesn't have a `CFBundleName`, its executable name is used instead. For missing `CFBundleVersion`, `(unknown version)` is used. This typically occurs when a command line tool without a bundle calls CFNetwork.

I don't think there is any documentation for this, and the default User Agent should be treated as a debugging facility instead of a specified behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just looking for some kind of external supporting content from someone at Apple. An openradar, a tweet, or a mailing list post would be fine as well.

Comment: I interned in CFNetwork team during the summer and read the code that generated User-Agent. I don’t think anyone touched it for the last decade or so, therefore it should be rather stable