# Connection issue in IOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]  . THIS is PLIST

```
 NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@ & user_type=%@",_emailID.text,_password.text, user_type];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"my url"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn) {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@" , error);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSLog(@"Connected %@",connection); 
}
```

I'm using this code in my Login form to POST data from email and password fields. i'm facing an error and not getting any response. 
Error is:

> 2017-05-01 10:58:06.236 PK.Estate[13412:4023436] App Transport
>   Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it
>   is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's
>   Info.plist file. 2017-05-01 10:58:06.397 PK.Estate[13412:4022282]
>   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x608000253260 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "The resource could not be
>   loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a
>   secure connection." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=url,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection., NSErrorFailingURLKey=url}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=url, NSErrorFailingURLKey=url,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the
>   App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure
>   connection.}

Comment: You should use HTTPS exclusively.  If you must use http then see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi for how to do it.

Comment: i know there r much more answers on satck overflow and other site i have applied them nut the issue is still there

Comment: i have tried this link also but not working its about 4 days the problem is still there. @JonRose

Comment: isn't `email=%@&password=%@ & user_type=%@` should be `email=%@&password=%@&user_type=%@` there is space before user_type & after password

Comment: try to add in your plist file : You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

For example,

 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000005f020 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}}} this error . @FahimParkar

Comment: i have done that before but same error man. @KKRocks

Comment: in which plist ..there are many plist file in project.

Comment: i didn't understand? @KKRocks

Comment: Im using Xcode 8 and IOS9

Comment: did you added this in plist....?

Comment: yes i have added that. @KKRocks

Comment: ok then in which plist that you need to cross check

Comment: im not familiar with that error I'm doing this for first time can u explain what r u saying. @KKRocks

Comment: try this steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817873/3901620

Comment: in a link where there is written in a bracket (1 item) when is do this in my plist there is written (0 item). how it can be change to 1. @KKRocks

Comment: if not sure first take backup then remove all your added line from plist which are you have recently add. and follow steps : ** right click on plist > open as source code**. and add on top this line <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>

Comment: did you try with `password=%@&user_type=%@` as there are spaces in your code? your code says `password=%@ & user_type=%@`

Comment: no there is no space . @FahimParkar

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using http in your url url. If you are using this make changes in plist
[image]

Comment: when i write App Transport Security Settings to dictionary it shows me 0items in a bracket. @Vinay Kumar

Comment: Please add App Tranport Security first and then click on drop down on the left most side off App Transport. Then click on plus button and then add "Allow Arbitrary Loads"

Comment: If sitting facing issue please edit your question and screen shot of your Info.plist page

Comment: it first show message "Connection Successful" and then shows same error. @Vinay Kumar

Comment: Please add screen shot of your plist

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800024c1b0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}}}   again same error. @Vinay Kumar

Comment: i have added above in a question check that out. @Vinay Kumar

Comment: As I am seeing in you screen shot Allow Arbitrary Loads is out side App Transport security. Please on drop down on the left side of the App Tranport Security  and then click on plus btn on right of the App Transport Security. Please look care fully in my screen shot.

Comment: App Transport Security showing 1 dictionary item or not?

Comment: check the edited question i have added screen shot. @Vinay Kumar

Comment: @HamzaImran Please check my screen shot care fully. I have used App Transport Security not NSAppTransport

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800024de60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}}}
error again . @Vinay Kumar

Comment: have u find any solution?  @Vinay Kumar