# http get vue.js + node.js returns empty data

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, http-get

I'm doing a project with vue + nativescript

the function app.get is not triggerd when I'm calling it from the vue project

this call :

```
const urlChannels = 'http://localhost:3001/sources';
  axios.get(urlChannels)
   .then(response => {
     store.commit('setTasks', {
       channels: response.data,
     });
   }) 
 }
```

returns :"data":"","status":null,"statusText":"" as if the server is off,(**the call itself is valid it works with other apis**)

**but simple test with angularjs on the browser returns the valid needed data**

this is my nodejs :

```
app.get('/sources', function (req, res) {
  res.set({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
});
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json'})
  let data = getNews.getSources()
  res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  //res.json(data); also tried this same resualt
})
```

Comment: Why are you using res.end() instead of res.send()?

Comment: Also, are you sure urlChannels has the correct url?  Can you show us how that's generated?

Comment: I've tried all sorts of option before the res.end.. it is important to mention that a simple ajax call from a test request in angularjs does bring the data succesfully updated the question

Comment: What does getNews.getSources() return?

Comment: I found the problem, it's a security thing with ios, they don't allow http calls, only https (I run the project on an ios emulator)

Answer (score 0):

res.end() is intended for ending the response without data (see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html).

If you want to return json, the easiest way is to use res.json():

```
app.get('/sources', function (req, res) {
    res.set({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET'
    });
    let data = getNews.getSources()
    res.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it's a security thing with ios, they don't allow http calls, only https (I run the project on an ios emulator)

[The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi)