# WebView in MacOS: How to request file system permissions correctly

Tags: macos, webview, rust, wkwebview

It may be because I'm **not** developing a **traditional Swift app**, instead I'm using the https://github.com/zserge/webview library to develop a cross platform app.

My app has 2 parts, divided into **2 different threads**: one thread launches the window and displays a JS app. The second thread contains a **background server** bound to an ephemeral port and serves a json api, written in Rust. The **Rust side** is also the one **talking** with the **File System** and making all requests. On Linux I don't have any problem, but on Mac it works only when requesting resources from root and home directories but not from Documents/Desktop etc

The first problem I had when running it on Mac has been allowing access to the server from the window: I had to add a new entry to the **info.plist** file, according to this answer in stackoverflow: [The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631184/the-resource-could-not-be-loaded-because-the-app-transport-security-policy-requi)

This resolved the issue I had talking to the server bound to the ephemeral port. Truth be said I have to also say that now it requests me to allow access to external resources every time I launch the app.

But, when trying to execute a function which **requires access** from the Rust side to the **Desktop** (for example), it doesn't work and it does not show any popup and never did

Btw, if you want to have a look at the final product, maybe to help you understand better the app, have a look here: http://getdevspace.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check the `ch` mode file system

Even had the same problem so i checked the `ch mode so it worked`

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask you what do you mean? chmod? The app has executable permissions for the current user, so not problem with that.