# Installing CA certificate on android in system context

Tags: android, xamarin.android, certificate

I need to access a REST API by HTTPS from my Xamarin APP. Of course in my development environment, I don't use a publicly signed certificate but signed from my local CA. So I need to add my CA certificate to the trusted CAs on the Android emulator. After some google searches the first approach I've found was, to just drag and drop it into the emulator and then install it with the "Files" app. But this only seems to install it in the user context. Which my App doesn't seem to care about since it still did not accept the certificate from the API as trusted. So I searched for some more...

The next approach was to get the issuer hash value from the certificate, rename the file after it, disable `Google APIs` and `Google Play Store` and do this:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name_here> -writable-system

adb root
adb shell remount
adb push <cert_filename> /system/etc/security/cacerts
adb shell "chmod 664 /system/etc/security/cacerts/<cert_filename>"

adb reboot
```

This did work but has some downsides. Always launch the emulator with `-writable-system` which means I have to launch it manually instead of from Visual Studio, and keeping `Google APIs` and `Google Play Store` disabled. I don't know what difference it makes if I keep those APIs disabled.

I can't really believe that this is the only way to install a CA certificate. How is it done on a real device? I assume I can't just disable the google APIs there?

Comment: My advice to you is to avoid messing around with self signed certificates, because it can be a real headache.  Just build your app using `HTTP`, and then we you are finally ready to deploy, turn on SSL, and use a CA from a known authority.  The JVM should already ship with a cert for that CA in its truststore, and you should not have to do any configuration work at all.

Comment: Seems actually to be the easiest way

Comment: I can confirm it's definitely a headache with self signed certificates. Couldn't make it working at all on both plattforms and switched to `HTTP` as well. It's really disappointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim Biegeleisen's comment made me invest some time looking in the direction of accessing the API in plain text. Neither Android nor iOS do allow this by default. Fortunate enough it is possible to allow it for specific domains which I think is an acceptable solution:

### Android

Found here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/cleartext-http-android-network-security/

1. Add the following file and folder under resources in the Android project:
   `xml\network_security_config.xml`
2. Add lines like this to the file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
      <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain> <!-- Debug port -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">xamarin.com</domain>
      </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

3. In `Properties\AssemblyInfo.xml` Add `android:networkSecurityConfig` to the application header:

```
    <manifest>
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        ...
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

### iOS

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33306373/3883521

In `info.plist` Add Something like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>domain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

change `domain.com` to your domain...